# Using Kotlin to develope an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, kotlin, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to use Kotlin to develop a plugin for Eclipse? The project I'm working on uses Maven Tycho and OSGi.

To prevent misunderstandings, this is not about the [Kotlin Eclipse Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/kotlin-plugin-eclipse), but about developing a custom plugin using the Kotlin language.

I added a dependency to the Kotlin stdlib in my `pom.xml`, but that doesn't seem to be enough just yet.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Since there are a lot of potentially relevant files (`MANIFEST.MF`, `pom.xml`, ...) I thought it might be easier to just link the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Tornac/slr-toolkit/tree/kotlin/plugins/de.tudresden.slr.questionnaire.

Only the code in `plugins/de.tudresden.slr.questionnaire` is mine, and I only care about adding Kotlin code to that particular plugin. My attempt to integrate Kotlin can be found on the `kotlin` branch. All the changes can be found in this commit: https://github.com/Tornac/slr-toolkit/commit/18f8f6de3a35644ef1ae595024667f4bdd10b604

During compilation, the following error is briefly shown:
`ERROR: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Unit'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library (5, 14)`.

Kotlin:

```
// file: KtTest
package de.tudresden.slr.questionnaire

class KtTest {
    fun doStuff() {
        System.out.println("hello world, this is kt!");
    }
}
```

Java:

```
// trying to call KtTest's method from Java
new KtTest().doStuff();
```

Stacktrace caused by calling doStuff():

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/tudresden/slr/questionnaire/KtTest
    at de.tudresden.slr.questionnaire.QuestionnaireView$1.mouseDown(QuestionnaireView.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at de.tudresden.slr.app.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.tudresden.slr.questionnaire.KtTest cannot be found by de.tudresden.slr.questionnaire_0.2.6.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: I think that's possible because [it is possible to create plug-ins in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446389/how-to-write-eclipse-rcp-applications-with-scala) and because parts of the [Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse IDE](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-eclipse) seem to be written in Kotlin. You could try to mimic the way Scala plug-ins are written or contact the developers/users of the Kotlin Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is possible. However, it appears to only work for older versions of Eclipse using JDK 8.

I cannot really comment on the Maven build, but I am facing a similar problem when building directly from Eclipse without a Maven plugin. I did quite extensive research to find the root of the problem. In particular, I created a minimal setup using the plugin templates provided by Eclipse when creating a new Plug-in project. Creating such a project from a template, adding the Kotlin nature and porting one of the classes to Kotlin reliably produces `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, while the IDE does not complain about any errors.

Looking at the developer documentation of the Kotlin plugin, they suggest using a setup based on Eclipse Oxygen and JDK 8. Indeed, I found this to work for my minimal plugin setup. I did more tests and found the latest version of Eclipse that works for my setup is Eclipse 2020-06 with JDK 8. Newer versions of Eclipse require JDK 11 and show the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error. I also tried Eclipse 2020-06 with JDK 11, which also shows the same error.

Note that this appears to be not at all a problem with plugin development in Eclipse. It rather seems to be a fundamental problem of the Kotlin plugin and with developing mixed Java and Kotlin applications. See my question here: [Is ist possible to build mixed Kotlin and Java applications with a recent Eclipse and JDK11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095816/is-ist-possible-to-build-mixed-kotlin-and-java-applications-with-a-recent-eclips)

Comment: Did you manage to get it working with newer JDKs? What I'd like to avoid is losing weeks to setup the RCP/PDE project.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My recommendation: if you need Eclipse then stay away from Kotlin. Looking at the recent activity in the GitHub repo of the Kotlin plugin, I don't expect any fixes soon. I found this [fork](https://github.com/bvfalcon/kotlin-eclipse-2021) of the plugin, which looks a bit more promising, but it also does not solve the problem (yet).

Comment: Thanks! You can have a look at the IntelliJ plugin Eclipse PDE Partial. It's still really new but it might be a good alternative in a couple months.

Comment: Thanks, this could actually come in very handy for our project.

Comment: it should get more popular, then it would attract contributions. PDE is a bit of a niche tho...